# Dynamically remove variables containing a value

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>     hospital      region     place     exemption      low      
>     NotValue      NotValue    30           3        NotValue
> ```

I have totally 100 variables. I would like to remove all variables containing "NotValue" dynamically in the sense that I cannot list all the variable names.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A data set is a rectangle of cells arranged in rows (observations) and columns (variables).   
The cells of a row can be organized using an ARRAY statement (ie `ARRAY charvars _character_;` makes each character variable addressable as `charvars[i]`) , Arrays can be iterated over with a DO loop. Do you want to remove rows that contain a cell with a 'NotValue', or a column that has 'NotValue' in all rows?

Comment: Hi, I would like to remove all the columns containing "NotValue" columnwise

Comment: Should the column contain just one value of "NotValue" to be removed?

Comment: Yes, the data set contains only one row for each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to iterate through all of your columns and save the variable name into a space-separated list every time a variable's value is "NotValue." You can pass this into a macro variable and create your desired dataset with another data step.

```
data _null_;
    set have;
    array charvars[*] _CHARACTER_;
    length dropvars $3200.;

    do i = 1 to dim(charvars);
        if(charvars[i] = 'NotValue') 
            then dropvars = catx(' ', dropvars, vname(charvars[i]));
    end;

    call symputx('dropvars', dropvars);
run;

data want;
    set have;
    drop &dropvars;
run;
```

```
place     exemption      
30        3
```